# update text constantly through for() loop and Handler

Tags: android, loops, textview, handler, freeze

I am working on a Testing Project for me , just so I could learn more , so now I need to update the text of a `TextView` constantly every 250 milliseconds through a `for(;;)` loop , it happens after a Button click ... My problem is that whenever I press that button my app freezes (Yes my button is totally working , verified through previous testings) , I am using a handler to the Main thread doesn't get affected while the `Runnable` is up ... Here is my code of the Button and Handler ...

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        B3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        for(;;){
                            String a = Shells.sendSingleCommand("free");//Here I send a command "free" and it returns its output 
                            text.setText(a);//text is my TextView which is used through my experimentations ... 
                            synchronized(this){
                                try{
                                    wait(250);
                                }catch(Exception e){

                                }
                        }

                        }
                    }
                });
                }

        });
```

If you need anymore info ask please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `handler.postDelayed` for updating textview constantly every 250 milliseconds instead of using `for loop` to avoid freeze current Activity as :

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
B3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  handler.post(runnable);  
                }

        });
Runnable runnable=new Runnable(){  
  @Override  
    public void run() {  
       String a = Shells.sendSingleCommand("free");
       text.setText(a);
       handler.postDelayed(runnable, 250);  
     }  
 };
```

Comment: We both answered in the same way :) hence im deleting my answer .

Comment: This gives a compilation error. `runnable` inside `runnable` declaration gives `not initialized` error.

Comment: @Sudhanshu: not getting you plz explain

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Yeah. My Android Studio gives me an error `runnable might not have been initialized` on the line `handler.postDelayed(...` and stops me from compiling the project

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I had to solve it using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15183112/1450945) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Android doesnt allow you to do long tasks in the main thread. If you need to do something like this I recommend moving the for loop and depdendent code into a separate thread..